# Controller is not detecting Model

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

Here in my Project Controller is not detecting Model.Am using ASP.net MVC3 ,Visual Studio 2010
But my other projects are working as well.How can i rectify this. I have re-installed VS2010 2 times but its working for this project.

**Here is my Controller Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace OfficeAuto.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(LoginModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (DataAccess.DAL.UserIsValid(model.UserName, model.Password))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Username or Password");
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult FranchIndex()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple mistake; not a big problem

You didn't add your Model reference:

```
using OfficeAuto.Models;
```